# Topic for motor current

Tags: ros, best-practices, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

is there a standard topic to output currents used by a motor? I know i can give efforts of motors in the joint state message but i also would like to provide the raw current values of the measurement.
Do i just use a std_msgs topic like Float64 or is there something better?
And is there a naming convention for things like this? If so could someone point me to the REP?

Best Regards
Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211635/topic-for-motor-current/) by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2015-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One example message type that exposes actuator currents (but also many, many other fields) is the [pr2_mechanism_msgs::ActuatorStatistics](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_mechanism_msgs/blob/master/msg/ActuatorStatistics.msg).

`std_msgs`, as suggested in the original answer defines floats and float arrays, but does not contain message types with specific actuator current semantics.  If you don't find a suitable existing alternative, you can create a simple message that wraps a `Float64[]`.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) on 2015-06-19**:
Thanks. I Went for the Foat64 Array. I am not entirely happy with it as you dont get a mapping of motor to the value but i wanted to keep the dependencies to non standard packages low. Also creating a new message just for such a "debug" topic seemed exessive.